# Problem with handling path length

Tags: c, utf-8

I'm creating library which will be used for file manipulations, both on linux and windows. So I need to handle paths, the main requirements is that my functions will recieve strings in UTF8 format. But it causes some problems, one of them is I'm using `MAX_PATH` on windows and `PATH_MAX` in linux, to represent static path variables. In the case of ASCII characters there will be no problem, but when path contains unicode characters, the length of path will be twice shorter if unicode char requires 2 bytes per char, 3 times shorter if unicode char requires 3 bytes per char and so on. So is there good solution for this problem?

Thanks in advance!

p.s. sorry for my english.

Answer (score 4):

At least on Linux, your concern seems misplaced. Linux (and POSIX in general) treats paths as an opaque blob of bytes terminated by "\0". It does not concern itself with how those bytes are translated to characters. That is, PATH_MAX specifies the max length of a path name in bytes, not in characters.

So if the path names contains >= 0 multibyte UTF-8 characters, then it just means that the max path length in characters is <= PATH_MAX.

Answer (score 1):

UTF-8 is multibyte encoding format ranging from 1 to 4 bytes per character. 
As you want to statically define max path value, you may need to define max path as `n*4` (where `n` is the path length in ASCII characters you want to define) to accommodate UTF-8 encoded characters.

Comment: You cannot define PATH_MAX: it is a system constant, fixed in the filesystem.

Comment: Yes, but it is the worst case

Comment: I did not mean to define MAX_PATH/PATH_MAX (I never mentioned these macros :)) but instead defining own max path value as n*4

Comment: Well yes, but you will make no one happy if you limit them to ¼ their customary length. You must take the encoding (and normalization, if any) into account that is appropriate for whichever filesystem you’re no.

Comment: Instead of using n*4 bytes for each character, IMHO it is better to use dynamic string character.

Comment: UTF-8 *is already* dynamically sized per character.  It’s UTF-32 that uses 4 bytes per character. UTF-16 is also dynamically sized per character, but you waste more space because the chunk size is too big, just like filesystems with big blocks and small files. That’s why UTF-8 is the optimal format for encoding Western text.

Answer (score 1):

That totally depends on what you need.

If you want MAX_PATH number of ***bytes***, you simply define a buffer as `char name[MAX_PATH]`. If you want `MAX_PATH` number of ***characters***, you define a buffer as `char name[MAX_PATH * 4]`, as UTF-8 encodes each Unicode character as a variable number of 1 to 4 octets.

In a word, as janneb points out, `MAX_PATH (or PATH_MAX)` specifies ***the number of underlying bytes*** instead of characters.

Comment: "In a word, ... MAX_PATH (or PATH_MAX) specifies the number of underlying bytes instead of characters." I know about it, I want MAX_PATH of characters, the method you offer above is the worst case, I want something more effective, than allocating 4*MAX_PATH bytes for each string.

Comment: If you want something more effective, then allocate PATH_MAX bytes because the system isn't capable of handling longer paths anyway, as explained in my answer. If you get a longer string as input to your library, you need to return an error, or truncate the string.

Comment: This is not solution, because in case of unicode characters the length of path which my lib can handle will be very short.

Comment: What's the value in handling path names longer than the system itself is capable of handling, one might then ask. Or conversely, if you don't care about system limits, why this discussion about PATH_MAX in the first place?

Comment: @janneb, I missunderstand your first reply[second I even don't understand, my english is not good enough for it)], I think I will do like you writed, with only one exception, I will check the num of characters in the path, instead of checking num of bytes.

Answer (score 0):

Doesn’t Microsoft use either UCS-2 or UTF-16 for its pathnames, and that so MAX_PATH   has a length that reflects 16-bit **code units**, not even proper characters?

I know that Apple uses UTF-16, and that each component in a pathname can be up to 256 UTF-16 **code units** not characters, and that it normalized to something approximating NFD from a long time ago.

I suspect you will have to first normalize if necessary, such as to NFD for Apple, then encode to your native filesystem’s internal format, and then check the length.

When you do that comparison, it is critical to remember that Unix uses 8-bit code units, Microsoft and Apple use 16-bit code units, and that no one seems to bother to actually use abstract characters. They could do that if they used UTF-32, but nobody wastes that much space in the filesystem.  Pity, that.