# Iterate backwards through a utf8 multibyte string

Tags: c, string, utf-8, iteration

I use a slightly modified version of this function `is_utf8` https://stackoverflow.com/a/1031773/275677 to extract UTF8 sequences from a character array, returning the sequence and how many bytes in it so that I can iterate over a string in this way.

However I would now like to iterate *backwards* over a string (`char *`). What is the best way to do this?

---

My guess is to try to classify the last four, three, two and one bytes of the string as utf8 (four times) and pick the longest.

However, is it ever the case that utf8 is ambigious? For example can `aaaabb` parsed as `aaaa.bb` also be parsed (backwards) as `aa.aabb` where `aa`, `aaaa`, `bb` and `aabb` are valid utf8 sequences?

Comment: For Windows I would use `MultiByteToWideChar()` to covert the string into Unicode and then do an easy iteration.

Comment: UTF-8 is never ambiguous. This is the whole point of UTF-8.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

A string consists of a series of UTF-8 sequences. All UTF-8 sequences:

- **EITHER** consist of exactly one octet (byte to you and me) with the top bit clear
- **OR** consist of one octet with the two topmost bits set, followed by one or more octets with bit 7 set and bit 6 clear.

See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Utf8#Description for details.

So what you need to do is to check whether the character concerned has bit 7 set and bit 6 clear, and if so step back one, taking care not to go beyond the start of the string (note that if the string is well formed, this won't happen).

Untested C-ish pseudocode:

```
char *
findPrevious (const char *ptr, const char *start)
{
    do
    {
        if (ptr <= start)
            return NULL; /* we're already at the start of the string */
        ptr--;
    } while ((*ptr & 0xC0) == 0x80);
    return ptr;
}
```

Comment: You got the second condition wrong. You mean bit 7 set and **bit 6** clear (assuming you count from 0).

Comment: @R.. doh - thanks - fixed. The pseudocode got that right I think.

Comment: +1 Ideas: 1) If the string is assumed to be well formed, the `(ptr <= start)` need not be in the loop, but before the loop.  2:) maybe `const char *`?

Answer (score 1):

This looks helpful. From the depths of memory I recalled that you can tell just by peaking at the first one or two bits of each byte - this makes it trivial to see how long the string should be, then use the original function just to validate it.

> UTF-8 characters are either single bytes where the left-most-bit is a 0 or multiple bytes where the first byte has left-most-bit 1..10... (with the number of 1s on the left 2 or more) followed by successive bytes of the form 10... (i.e. a single 1 on the left). Assuming that your string is well-formed you can loop over all the bytes and increment your "character count" every time you see a byte that is not of the form 10... - i.e. counting only the first bytes in all UTF-8 characters.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/7108478/275677

also the table at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8#Description